# Changing the logging level in glassfish isn't working

Tags: logging, glassfish, log4j, axis

I'm trying to change the logging level for org.apache.axis in glassfish. I've added "org.apache.axis.level=ERROR" to the logging.properties file in the domain folder in glassfish, and "asadmin list-log-levels" gives "org.apache.axis ", but when I run my application I still see tons of DEBUG statements from org.apache.axis.

Should I be setting the logging level elsewhere? In my application or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. There was a logging configuration file within my actual application. Once I added "log4j.logger.org.apache.axis=INFO" to that, the DEBUG statements went away. Apparently changing the glassfish logging levels doesn't actually effect your application logging levels.